# How to Easily Remove Unwanted Parts in HTML Table Cells Using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, html-table, css-tables

I have series of different occurrences of table cells in some html files as shown in this image:

http://screencast.com/t/MqGHN2iwfd

Apart from the beginning and end of each cell, they have the following parts in common:

.net/?mobile=true

/spotlightProfile.htm?f=mkt&v=

/#stats

I want to either be able to remove all the parts that look like that once

OR be able to remove one-by-one in notepad++:

1. the url part that precede .net/?mobile=true
2. the url parts before and after /spotlightProfile.htm?f=mkt&v= and
3. the url part before /#stats

Furthermore, please, I also want to be able to remove the duplicate occurrence also in Notepad++

Thanks a lot in anticipation for helping out.

Comment: I don't know about Notepad++, but PHPStorm/WebStorm can do it. It enables you to search and replace based on regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex would look something like this.

```
Search for: (.*)(\/\?mobild=true|\/spotlightProfile\.htm\?f=mkt&v=|\/#stats)?(.*)
Replace With: \1\3
```

Basically we create 3 groups:

1. before the expression you match,
2. the expression you trying to replace
3. the rest of the line

Comment: Thanks so much anazimok. I was eventually able to deal with the links one-by-one after going to revise the regex syntax very well. However, thanks so much because I learned a lot from the following steps you gave: 

"Basically we create 3 groups:

before the expression you match,
the expression you trying to replace
the rest of the line"

Comment: Can you guide me on how I can remove the duplicate at the bottom? Thanks.